# Who is he? Who is me?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

With potent, flowery words speak I,

Of something common, vulgar, or maybe dry;

I weave webs of pedantic prose,

In an effort to befuddle those,

Who think I wile the time away,

In lofty things, above all day

The common kind that lingers where

Monadic beings live and fare;

Practical I may not be,

But life, it seems, is full of me!

---

Who is me?

Source

> https://www.riddles.nu/topics/life

Comment: Please note, if you follow the link it also contains the answer. Don't click it if you want no spoilers.

Answer (score 1):

This made me think of:

> Charlotte from Charlotte's Web (who is me?)

I don't know if I recall much of the story, but these are my thoughts:
Who is he?

> Wilbur

With potent, flowery words speak I,

> Writes words in her web. Spider webs are both strong and silky looking.

Of something common, vulgar, or maybe dry;

> Pigs are common, culturally vulgar (?), many extrapolations.

I weave webs of pedantic prose,

> Could describe Charlotte's teaching to Wilbur as well as the show of having the words in the web.

In an effort to befuddle those,

> The people may find seeing words in spider webs to be confusing.

Who think I wile the time away, In lofty things, above all day

> Up in the rafters of the barn.

The common kind that lingers where Monadic beings live and fare;

> Alright, Monadic is a stretch, but spiders are still common in houses and such.

Practical I may not be, But life, it seems, is full of me!

> Practical? Yes and no? Controls insect populations, but it's less practical when we find them and (most) people spend time dealing with that. And, at least where I live, spiders are everywhere!!